# Let flex-container only use necessary width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

A flex-container defined like

```
display: flex; 
flex-flow: column wrap;
height: 4em;
```

will consume all available width as seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Su4Wq/1/). How can I make it behave more like a table and consume only necessary space?

Note: I don't want to assign a certain width because I don't know the desired width beforehand and want to place other content in the remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to get *table* behavior.  You can get *inline-block* behavior:

```
.foo {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

The distinction here is that *table* forces the content that follows to appear afterwards instead of on the same line.

Comment: Hm, just tried that in an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thorbenb/Su4Wq/2/), but it still does not only use necessary space, just a bit less that `display: flex`

Comment: If this is a browser specific problem, knowing *which* browser matters just a little bit.  Opera 12 displays it exactly as expected ([fiddle with borders](http://jsfiddle.net/Su4Wq/5/)), Chrome does not and there doesn't seem to be a work around, Firefox is wrong because it doesn't support wrapping.

Comment: I just tried Opera 16, 17, the latest 18, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE9. In none of them it works. It's not that browser specific, but *only* Opera 12 is not good enough ;) But - for me - the most important browser would be Opera 16

Comment: The distinction here is that Opera 12 is still using Presto, Opera 15+ is using Webkit/Blink.  Of course Firefox (doesn't support wrapping), Safari (doesn't support wrapping) and IE9 (doesn't support Flexbox at all) won't work.  I have a hard time believing dedicated Opera users are upgrading off of v12 because 15+ stripped away pretty much every feature that made Opera what it is.

Comment: Opera 15 (and 16, 17 and 18 which slowly add useful features of 12) attracted a lot of new users, but that's a different discussion. Opera 12 is history and there are very few people using it, I don't see much point in testing for it.